# What is an Ipsum Word™?

Tags: pattern, language, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an **Ipsum Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| IPSUM Words™ | Not IPSUM Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BLEEDING | BLOTTING |
| PROVED | PROVOKE |
| HARM | HEALING |
| LOSING | WINNING |
| TOE | ARM |
| QUARKS | QUINTET |
| HI | GOODBYE |
| AMAZING | DISGUST |
| EXIT | FOXY |
| KENTUCKY | CAROLINA |
| ZIG | ZAG |
| MOUNTAIN | PEAKS |

The CSV version:

```
IPSUM Words™,Not IPSUM Words™
BLEEDING,BLOTTING
PROVED,PROVOKE
HARM,HEALING
LOSING,WINNING
TOE,ARM
QUARKS,QUINTET
HI,GOODBYE
AMAZING,DISGUST
EXIT,FOXY
KENTUCKY,CAROLINA
ZIG,ZAG
MOUNTAIN,PEAKS
```

These are not the only examples of Ipsum Words™, many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Comment: Wow, 15 hours in, and not even a comment. Stackers must be truly stumped!

Comment: I'm lost on what to do... Ipsum is related with Lorem Ipsum, a common filler text

Comment: @North very true... and what is that text?

Comment: @sensoray Um it's Latin, and its a filler text?

Comment: @Sensoray i think it is also called "greeking", anything to do with that?

Comment: @North it is. I'd more so just focus on that than the filler part

Comment: @Riddler it probably doesn't have to do with the meaning of the words, then.

Comment: @Sensoray not to put too fine a point on it, but Loren Ipsum isn't Latin.  It's Latin sounding nonsense.  Still...

Comment: @Riddler there is definitely a rule, it's not nonsense. I did slight changes in some words to try and help y'all pinpoint the differences. Also wanted to make sure to use most of the letters of the alphabet on both sides to help rule out some other stuff.

Comment: @Riddler omg okay... SO if it ISNT meaning, length, or letters, what else is there? XD

Comment: Next time ill post it in meta area of question development and get feedback first then. I thought I was making it easier by doing a variety of words, not harder.

Comment: @Riddler what in the world is your problem??  Holy crap. There IS a rule, a very structured one. Why in the world would i spend so much time making this question if there wasnt an answer? Its not broad, there isnt many things that fit this. Only 1. It's not something I made up, its REAL.  I haven't necissarily done this format before, but based it on how others did it. I mainly said i would take similar word-pattern questions to meta in the future if it seems I'm somehow not doing this type of puzzle correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89182/discussion-between-sensoray-and-riddler).

Comment: @Riddler seems to have forgotten to delete the last comment, so there is at least _some_ sense to what otherwise appears to be the OP's monologue. Obviously I can't know what Riddler posted, but I'm sad to see that the OP answered their own quesion just to prove that there is a rule. For what it's worth, I don't think there was anything wrong with the question.

Comment: I apologize, obviously there is an answer to this. I thought they confirmed there was no answer. My mistake.

Comment: @Sensoray As reconciliation for my mistake I have spread some love to some other lesser voted questions that I liked of yours. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is:

> In [numerology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerology), latin letters are assigned a certain value and when placed in a word, they are summed, and then summed again until only left with one #. Ipsum words have an even sum. Here is the chart:   [image]

They are named Ipsum Words because:

> Numerology is the devine/mystic belief that there is a relationship between numbers and events. Numerology is usually associated with the paranormal and divination, which most people consider "nonsense". Since it assigns Latin letters a value, I wanted the title for these words to be "Latin nonsense", which Loren Ipsum is.

Here are the Ipsum Words:

> **Bleeding:** 2+3+5+5+4+9+5+7 = 40 = 4+0 = 4
> **Harm:** 8+1+9+4 = 22 = 2+2 = 4
> **Losing:** 3+6+1+9+5+7 = 31 = 4
> **Toe:** 2+6+5 = 13 = 1+3 = 4
> **Quarks:** 8+3+1+9+2 = 24 = 2+4 = 6
> **Hi:** 1+7 = 8
> **Amazing:** 1+4+1+8+9+5+7 = 35 = 3+5 = 8
> **Exit:** 5+6+9+2 = 22 = 2+2 = 4
> **Kentucky:** 2+5+5+2+3+3+2+7 = 29 = 2+9 = 11 = 1+1 = 2
> **Zig:** 8+9+7 = 24 = 2+4 = 6

Here are Non-Ipsum Words:

> **Blotting:** 2+3+6+2+2+9+5+7 = 36 = 3+6 = 9
> **Heals:** 8+5+1+3+1 = 18 = 1+8 = 9
> **Winning:** 5+9+5+5+9+5+7 = 45 = 4+5 = 9
> **Arm:** 1+9+4 = 14 = 1+4 = 5
> **Quintet:** 8+3+9+5+2+5+2 = 34 = 3+4 = 7
> **Goodbye:** 7+6+6+4+2+7+5 = 37 = 3+7 = 10 = 1+0 = 1
> **Disgust:** 4+9+1+7+3+1+2 = 27 = 2+7 = 9
> **Foxy:** 6+6+6+7 = 25 = 2+5 = 7
> **Carolina:** 3+1+9+6+3+9+5+1 = 37 = 3+7 = 10 = 1+0 = 1
> **Zag:** 8+1+7 = 16 = 1+6 = 7